# 'cdadr' on nested data list in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

While studying `cons`, `cdr` and `car` to handle lists I tried following :

```
(cadr '('(1) '(2)))
'(2)
```

which gives the second item in the list as expected.
Whereas following gives :

```
(cdadr '('(1) '(2)))
((2))
```

How is data being concerted to code and still not giving error?

How was this evaluated?

cdr on '(2) should give nil, which is does. Why not above?

[I am new to both clisp and stackoverflow so pardon me.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`quote`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm) is a special operator which returns its single unevaluated argument. The form `(quote ...)` can be abbreviated using [`'`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dc.htm) as `'...`.  Since the `'` is handled by the reader, the form

```
'('(1) '(2)))
```

is actually read the same as

```
(quote ((quote (1)) (quote (2)))
```

The outermost application `quote` to the the argument`((quote (1)) (quote (2)))` returns that argument.  The `cadr` of that argument is the list

```
(quote (2))
```

whose first element is the symbol `quote`, and whose second element is a list of a single element `2`.

Answer (score 2):

Because of quotes. You should write `(cadr '((1) (2)))`.

With your list, `(caadr '('(1) '(2)))` yields `QUOTE`.

Actually, your list `'('(1) '(2))` is really `'((quote (1)) (quote (2)))`, which may show better why you get this result.

Comment: This is all correct, but I'ld suggest as a clarification for Lisp learners this additions: `'(2)` (the `cadr` in the question) is just a shorthand for `(quote (2))`. The `cdadr` is the rest (all but the first element) of the `cadr`, which is `((2))`.