# Whats the difference between '((1 2)(3 4)) and '('(1 2 )'(3 4)) in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The length of

```
(length (car '('(0)'(1 2 3)'(6 7))))
```

is being show 2 while the same

```
(length (car '((0)(1 2 3)(6 7))))
```

is correctly shown 1. so what does the the first expression actually represent?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18697105/1281433) isn't asking exactly the same thing, but its answers do answer this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quote character `'` is a reader macro. `'anything` expands into `(quote anything)`. So the first expression is shorthand for:

```
(length (car (quote ((quote (0))
                     (quote (1 2 3))
                     (quote (6 7)))
```

The first `quote` causes the parameter to be treated literally. That means that the `quote` expressions inside it are just lists that happen to begin with the symbol `quote`.

So the CAR of that list is the sub-list `(quote (0))`. It contains 2 elements: the symbol `quote` and the list `(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER 8 > '((0)(1 2 3)(6 7))
((0)
 (1 2 3)
 (6 7))

CL-USER 9 > '('(0)'(1 2 3)'(6 7))
((QUOTE (0))
 (QUOTE (1 2 3))
 (QUOTE (6 7)))
```